# JQuery - current table row of item

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs

I have a table with several rows and a "Details" button in one column in each row.
I need to get the current table row of the clicked Details button. Every button has the same class and id.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your buttons should never have the same ID. Same class is ok, but same id is not. It's meant to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delegate a click event from the table to the button selector, and get the closest `tr` on click, as follows:

```
$("#yourTable").on('click', '.details-button', function(){
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [jQuery parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to get the row element on button click.

```
$('.button').on('click',function() {
    console.log($(this).parent());
})
```

Also don't use same id's on elements.

Comment: This will actually get the closest parent, and in this case, will return a `td` (considering the button is directly inside the `td`) instead of the `tr`. We could do `.parent().parent()` too, but `closest()` is less verbose.

Comment: Oh yeah that is true.